# How to integrate a wiki into my website?

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

I would like to have wiki-editable parts on a site I'm coding (in php) and I could'nt find any tutorial about it.

Considering MediaWiki as an example, I would like to be able to include the tab list (Article, Talk, Read, Edit, History) and the actual contents, without the other parts which are the top create account/login thing, the left logo, menu and language links and the page footer, which are not relevant in this case.

I'm not asking for a direct answer here, since I'm sure this is not trivial and the integration must have some ramifications with external user account management, issues with the edit form's target page and post/get parameters management, and other things I can't think about right know. I need pointers to tutorials about this, or the right manual page.

**Wiki software choice**

MediaWiki seems like a reference among wiki implementations, and is most probably the best known to the average internet user. Because of its (supposedly) bigger user (coder) base, my guess is that MediaWiki has more chance to feature easy integration.

But I may very well be wrong and I'm willing to try out any wiki software.

Comment: you could certainly edit the media wiki template to do that.

Comment: What kind of site do you have? Is a word press or some type of CMS?

Comment: @Pjack, I'm coding it. It's not based on anything.

Comment: Then it should be a lot easier to use. You can customize the wiki and change the template. It has its own authentication system however that you might have to deal with. It's a pretty strong wiki. FYI mediawiki is the same wiki that Wikipedia uses. It's a project by the Wikimedia foundation which owns Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried harder and did it with the help of [Advice for integrating a blog and wiki in a custom site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427298/advice-for-integrating-a-blog-and-wiki-in-a-custom-site?rq=1) which suggests "Stripping Wordpress and MediaWiki of most of their respective visuals and including them both in the site using iframes."

and an answer to [Displaying a mediawiki within a iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357470/displaying-a-mediawiki-within-a-iframe) which resolves the Edit-button-not-working problem.

Comment: good work, thanks for letting us know, you can accept your own answer

Comment: BBCode may also fix the problem without external software nor the pain of integration.