# Mediawiki & Wordpress integration - but user database from *mediawiki*

Tags: wordpress, integration, mediawiki, single-sign-on

I have Mediawiki install with big existing userbase, but i want to integrate it seamless in new Wordpress blog. If it is possible to integrate MediaWiki with Wordpress using existing Mediawiki's user database ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745/wordpress-mediawiki-integration

Comment: This describes integrating MW *into* WP, and i need to integrate WP *into* MW

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I haven't tried this, because I want to integrate the other way around, but one solution to your problem might be to install the OpenID MediaWiki extension:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID

Then in Wordpress install the OpenID extension and configure it to only allow OpenID registrations from the url of your MediaWiki install.

I'll probably be using the same extensions, but configure them for use the other way around, as the other integration options mentioned above look out of date and difficult to maintain.