# Is it possible to pull MediaWiki into a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, wiki, mediawiki

We want to create a wiki page/system on our [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) site that resembles the Wikipedia/[MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) look.

Is it possible to do an install of MediaWiki or similar Wiki interface and have it appear within a set WordPress theme/frame?

Possibly pull it with an iFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without addressing the iframe right away, it is possible to [integrate WordPress and MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745/wordpress-mediawiki-integration) and [install a wiki plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways. The best I have found are using [Wikiful](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wikiful/) (a WordPress plugin) and [WPMW](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWPMW) (a MediaWiki extension).

Wikiful allows WordPress to display wiki pages and WPMW allows a wiki to use WordPress for user authentication.

If someone can add a way to *edit* wiki pages inside of WordPress's GUI to this answer, that would be amazing.